# gulp polymer-build not generating expected bundle?

Tags: gulp, polymer

I have the following gulp task (please see below), which I'm trying to run to automate the polymer build. However, all I'm seeing in the resulting /build folder is an index.html. No dependencies, and I was under the impression that the resulting file would be called shared-bundle.html. Also, it's not fetching any of my bower dependencies:

```
const PolymerProject = require('polymer-build').PolymerProject;
const project = new PolymerProject(require('./polymer.json'));
gulp.task('build', () => {
    mergeStream(project.sources(), project.dependencies())
        .pipe(project.bundler())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));
});
```

This is the documentation I was referencing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/polymer-build

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was just missing the entrypoint param here:

```
const project = new PolymerProject({entrypoint: 'my-page.html'});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add `entrypoint` to your `polymer.json`?